# Multi parameter template not playing nicely with friend declaration

Tags: c++, g++

The following snippet works fine in both Visual Studio and g++.

```
template<typename T> class BST;

template<typename T>
class BSTNode 
{
    friend class BST<T>;
...
```

while this snippet works fine in VS, but not g++

```
template<typename K, typename V> class Map;

template<typename K, typename V>
class MapPair
{

    friend class Map<typename K, typename V>;
     ...
```

What is wrong with this code? The errors I get are unhelpful, but here they are

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
error: provided for ‘template<class K, class V> struct Map’
error: friend declaration does not name a class or function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove `typename` from before `K` and `V`

Answer (score 1):

Say `friend class Map<K, V>;`. `typename` may only be used to qualify dependent names, which `K` and `V` are not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel pretty silly right now. Now I just wonder why VS didn't complain

Comment: VS has several "issues" with template processing, so you have to be careful what conclusions you draw from VS behaviour, unfortunately.